# Project 2003 SP2 failing to install SP3

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-project

I have Microsoft Project Professional 2003 installed (11.2.2005.1801.15, SP2).

I have been trying to open a MPP file created in a newer version so need the converter, which is part of SP3. But when I try to install the SP3 package (as downloaded from Microsoft's site) I get an error message box:

```
---------------------------
Project 2003 Service Pack 3 (SP3)
---------------------------
The expected version of the product was not found on your system.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Project (and Office) are licensed and otherwise work correctly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever seen this happen when the expected version genuinely was not on the system. What does "sent a MPP file from a newer version" mean?

**Things to try:**

1. Install the service pack from its [official download location](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FCC0627B-2C58-4A70-B808-4D7A1B26535E).
2. Go into Project Professional setup and use the **Detect and Repair** option.
3. Uninstall and reinstall Project Professional.
4. Contact Microsoft support.

Comment: What's the expected version, then? I'm running Project 2003 SP2 and Project 2003 SP3 give me this error message (even from the link you provided). If I try to follow its instructions when I open the (newer) MPP I'm met with a "that page is unavailable" because Microsoft can't keep their CMS up to date.

Comment: @Unsliced: I've edited my answer with some more suggestions. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following Microsoft support [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837826) discusses your problem.
The best advice it contains is perhaps to install using the [full sp3 installation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832671/), but better see if the other remarks do apply to you.